# Varying a size of instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have icospheres instanced on a sphere in the first screenshot and I want the icospheres to vary in size like the spheres in the second screenshot. How do I do that?
[image: Spheres and ecospheres]

[image: Attribute Randomize]

Comment: Random Value node into Scale (probably Map Range node would be needed too.

Comment: There are so many answers here describing how you can use the `Random Value` node together with `Instance on Points`, ...I am still looking for the appropriate duplicate. But as @vklidu said correctly: `Random Value` will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way. You could put a Scales instances in front of the Instances on point and connect a Random Value + Vector Math (in multiply) and add those to the scale
[image]

Here is an example: https://vimeo.com/653258060 AT minute 1:47

Comment: Probably enough too ... https://imgur.com/Sb5jyh1 :)

Comment: @vklidu yeah, but it was in case the OP needed the original scale for something else

Comment: If your answer should stand on its own and not rely on an external tutorial (as it would be preferred on this site), then your setup does not help at all. It's not adding anything to the original scale, it replaces it. And since the _Vector Math_ node just multiplies all random values with 0, resulting in setting all scales to 0 and thus making all instances disappear (as it does in the tutorial as well by the way, only after changing the multiplier to values different from 0 it starts to work), this answer is no solution.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the video is just an example, you could delete the link and the image is still showing the way, if the answer does not work for you, you could downvote it without any problem.

Comment: Explain to me how multiplying everything by 0 gets you random sized spheres. And that's all your answer shows.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I understood your point, not everyone will think logically and change the value numbers of a node in order to see a result and as I said, you are very welcome to down vote the answer and report it, there is no problem