# Radius size in instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have icospheres instanced on a sphere and when I vary their sizes, I get unwanted results like the one in the first screenshot.  I want the icospheres to vary in size while keeping their radius like the spheres in the second screenshot. How do I do that?
[image: Sphere and icospheres]
[image: Attribute randomize]

Comment: Please do not post the same question [several times](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283400/varying-a-size-of-instances), and take a closer look at the search function, because this question has essentially already been answered here a few times! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Change the random value to float and connect that directly to the Scale

[image]